# Best practice for storing type of object in a class

Tags: java, enums, constants

I have a transaction of two types:
- income
- expense

```
class Transaction {
    final public static int IN = 0x1, OUT = 0x2;
    final private int type;

    Transaction(int type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    // --- internal logic is same for both types ---
}

// create:
Transaction t = new Transaction(Transaction.IN);
```

What is the best practice for this case? I should declare an enum? Two clases? I should use Factory pattern?

Comment: The best practice is two classes: maybe `InTransaction` and `OutTransaction` or `IncomeTransaction` and `ExpenseTransaction`. Both could extend `Transaction` if that is useful.

Comment: What else is part of a Transaction?  Is the type simply a marker for later categorization, or will it drive a difference in behavior of the methods of Transaction?  If it's just a piece of data, what you've got is fine, but if the different Transactions will behave differently, you're better off creating different classes.

Comment: It's just a marker and It's used by the view module. The transaction internal logic is same for both.

Comment: Just declare an enum for this purpose.

Comment: The System.out is different, thats a good reason fr having two classs, you dont need the switch (which is a strong design smell).

Comment: I must expose only the class of transactions. The display is just one example (maybe my example is bad). The user can use as he wants and for what purpose he wants that marker.

Comment: What are you displaying?

Comment: Such as green text for IN and red text for OUT but in another module and we need to know which are IN and which are OUT. This Transaction class is an element of an array (history of transactions).

Comment: Perfect example for avoiding the switch. have two classes , both implement different getColor() methods, the base class the common functions and fields. The users do not even need to know your specialized classes.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using an `Enumeration` in such cases, because this way, you can restrict the possible values in a statically checked way:

```
enum TransactionType {
    Income, Expense;
}

class Transaction {
    final private TransactionType type;

    Transaction(TransactionType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public TransactionType getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

Otherwise, any `int` value could be provided to your constructor `Transaction(int type)`.

Another benefit of `enum`s is, that you later can provide them with some additional information if you like to (e.g. different formatting patterns or the like).

Answer (score 1):

This is really depending on what you find easiest. The advantage of enums is you can set it to any enum and transfer the instance and get the value out of itEnum example:

```
private enum ENUM{
    EX1, EX2
};
```

and call it like so:

```
private ENUM instance = ENUM.EX1;
```

And if you want to retrieve the value:

```
switch(instance){

case ENUM.EX1:

    break;
case ENUM.EX2:

    break;

}
```

Here is the enum example:

```
enum Transaction { 

    IN(0x1), OUT(0x2); 

    private int marker; 
    Transaction(int marker) { 
    this.marker = marker; 
    } 

}
```

Enum is easier, yes.

Comparativly:

The code is different, and calling is different. But not much.

The main difference is how you compare the value. You have to actually get the value of the instance(instance.getType()) in a switch loop.

Both are equally good, though in most cases I preffer enum as it saves me of creating another class as all I need is an enum. Though other times, enums just does not cut it. In your situation it does not appear like you can use enum(unless you change the codes to be "enum acceptable").

> What is the best practice for this case? I should declare an enum?

In this case? Maybe. It is really up to you. Enum is however the easiest way to store things in.

Comment: You can have a numeric code associated with an Enum (either by the ordinal or by having a field with the help of the constructor.

Comment: Could you explain that in a little simpler english?

Comment: An enum is supported for their purposes. If the assigned ordinal value of the constant is different than what you like you can still provide a constructor and do `IN(1)` which can map to a variable in the enum; doubt it's needed in this case though. There are other advantages to enums as well like being able to provide methods and type safety.

Comment: IN(0x1) still leads to unknown token though. I don't know a lot about enums as I haven't really used it for much besides strings but I always need to learn for later times

Comment: Your enum is improperly defined then. You need a constructor and an int to store it in.

Comment: If a constructor and integers to store it in are required for it to work, it kinda defeats the simplicity. Then the class option is easier

Comment: If you're only willing to use Java enums for the simplest of scenarios then you're missing out on a great advantage of them. The constructor doesn't make it any more complex to the client. Please give [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) a read.

Comment: According to that code, in order to define the variables IN and OUT it requires two variables; number one is 0x1 and there is no number 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121781/discussion-between-chieftwopencils-and-polarbear0106).

Answer (score 0):

Best practices really depends on the use case. Given what you added in the comments an `enum` seems like the better option. An `enum` can encapsulate additional information for the "marker". For example, you said you print with a color based on the transaction type. To avoid doing additional conditional logic you could add that information to the `enum` value itself. For example:

```
enum TransactionType {
    IN(Color.GREEN), OUT(Color.RED);

    public final Color TEXT_COLOR;

    TransactionType(Color textColor) {
        TEXT_COLOR = textColor;
    }
}
```

It also provides safer usage through compile-time checking. You can make your code more dummy-proof by letting the compiler check for correct `TransactionType`s. It's not completely dummy-proof though since you can still do `TransactionType.valueOf("DUMMY")` but it's better than needing to check against all possible goofs anywhere you might need to use the marker.

For example, you said there's a need to find the transactions of a given type. You might do that like this:

```
List<Transaction> ins = transactions.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getType() == TransactionType.IN).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It would be possible to throw a `42` in there if your class relied on an `int` value.

```
List<Transaction> ins = transactions.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getType() == 42).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Worst part is it would just return an empty list; no compile or runtime errors leaving you with the need to validate the value somewhere.

An additional note would be that, if it's truly just a marker, you might be able to replace the `Transaction` class completely with an `enum` but more information would be needed to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the context, but if you have:

```
public class Transaction {
    private double amount = 0.0d;
    public static Transaction newExpenseTx() {
        return new ExpenseTransaction();
    }
    public static Transaction newIncomeTx() {
        return new IncomeTransaction();
    }
    public void setAmount(double a) { amount = a; }
    public double getAmount() { return amount; }
    public abstract Color getColor();

    static class ExpenseTransaction extends Transaction {
        Color getColor() { return Color.RED; }
    }

    static class IncomeTransaction extends Transaction {
        Color getColor() { return Color.GREEN; }
    }
}
```

You can see that your caller does not need to know about the subclasses and you do not need to have any switch.

```
Transaction t1 = Transaction.newExpenseTx();
assertEquals("Exprense Transactions need to be red, has amount " +
                                                  t1.getAmount(),
                                             Color.RED, t1.getColor());
```

Of course if you need the type as a value, adding a TransactionType enum does not hurt.